# Convert data frame to numeric and dropna

Tags: python, pandas

I been using:

```
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dropna()
```

but since it's being deprecated I need to replace it with to_numeric

I've tried

```
df = pd.to_numeric
df = df.dropna()
```

Sample data:

```
Name  Race Fav Age  Weight Height Style Cut
John   D    K  23    120   23.5    DD   RET
Rose   Z    U  33    110   47.9    KZ   DEZ
James  Z    U  FF    UK    NOT     Z    R
```

Would like to convert to drop the rows that are non numeric

Output:

```
Name  Race Fav Age  Weight Height Style Cut
John   D    K  23    120   23.5    DD   RET
Rose   Z    U  33    110   47.9    KZ   DEZ
```

Comment: it depends on the data also did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas?

Comment: Add sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [399]: num_cols = df.columns[df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').any()]

In [400]: df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

In [401]: df = df[df.select_dtypes(['number']).notnull().all(1)]

In [402]: df
Out[402]:
   Name Race Fav   Age  Weight  Height Style  Cut
0  John    D   K  23.0   120.0    23.5    DD  RET
1  Rose    Z   U  33.0   110.0    47.9    KZ  DEZ

In [403]: df.dtypes
Out[403]:
Name       object
Race       object
Fav        object
Age       float64
Weight    float64
Height    float64
Style      object
Cut        object
dtype: object
```

Comment: I get this error:TypeError: ("to_numeric() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error'", 'occurred at index Age')

Comment: Perfect.  That Worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling `to_numeric` properly. Since it only applies to columns, if you want to apply it to all columns you'll have to use `pd.apply`

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
df = df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply` the `to_numeric` then `dropna`

```
df.apply(lambda x :pd.to_numeric(x, errors ='coerce'),axis=1).dropna()
```